# Summing bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, bessel-functions, analytic-functions

I want to evaluate the sum:
$$\sum_n e^{inz}J_n(x)J_{m-2n}(y)$$
And I wonder if there is any known identity that can help me make itt analytical.
I'm aware of some other similar Bessel identities, like Graf's and Gegenbauer's summation rules
$$\sum_n e^{inz}J_n(x)J_{n+m}(y)=J_m(w)e^{imP}$$
Where P and m have some geometrical interpretation, and also
$$\sum_n J_n(x)J_{m\pm n}(y)=J_m(x\pm y)$$
Guess they might be useful but I still don't see a way to evaluate the first sum.
If someone have an Idea I'll be grateful :)